# Broadcasting Multiple Arrays

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting

I have the following function that generates a double Gaussian.

```
def Model(wavelength_array, width):
    """Returns the model
    Parameters: wavelength_array: Full wavelength array. This is a constant
                width: width of the Gaussians. This varies.
    """

    Gaussian = lambda x, mean, std: np.exp(-((x[:, np.newaxis] - mean)/std)**2)

    separation = (3729.875-3727.092)/2
    lambda0 = wavelength_array[:,(len(wavelength_array[0])+1)//2]

    models = []
    for i,j in enumerate(wavelength_array):
        models.append(Gaussian(j, lambda0[i]-separation, width) + \
                           Gaussian(j, lambda0[i]+separation, width))

    models = np.asarray(models)

    return models
```

The wavelength_array is an array of arrays, and width is an array, e.g.:

```
wavelength_array = [[4500, 4502, 4504, 4506] [4502, 4504, 4506, 4508]]
width = np.arange(.1, .5, .1)
```

I would like to loop over every array in `wavelength_array` and every element in `width`. Naively, that would mean a double loop. However, I recently learned about broadcasting and have been able to broadcast the `width` portion of the code. Unfortunately, I still have a loop left that is looping over `wavelength_array` and I am unsure how I can also broadcast over this variable. If you have any suggestions and/or feedback on how I can vectorize this function completely and speed it up, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

So I might have misinterpreted a few things, feel free to clarify and I'll correct.

In general, you're trying to get a set of gaussian results, I'll lazily call them lower and upper, then add them together to get one final result. I'm also assuming the lambda0 is supposed to be a mean, rather than specifically the second index. If not, feel free to ignore that part.

```
lambda0 = wavelength_array.mean(axis=1)
#so the broadcasting dimensionality will work
lambda0 = lambda0[:, np.newaxis]
```

Now you should be able to just do all the ops in a broadcasting manner.

```
lower = np.exp(-((wavelength_array - (lambda0 - separation))/width)**2)
upper = np.exp(-((wavelength_array - (lambda0 + separation))/width)**2)

models = lower + uppper
```

Something like that?